# Exporting an HTML table to Excel

Tags: asp.net-mvc, excel, entity-framework, linq, export-to-excel

I have a dynamically generated HTML table.  I have an ActionResult method "GetOrders" that returns an OrderViewModel list object based on a daterange provided by the user.  After rendering the table, I would like to have a second Action Method that exports that data to an excel file.

My question is: Do I have to parse the HTML table that is rendered into a dataset/gridview, or is there a way to save the data that is being queried in the original "GetOrders" Action Method? That way I could pass it into a second function for the export.

I've provided some of the code to assist in understanding what I'm trying to accomplish..

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetOrders(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {

        var model = db.SalesOrderDetails
            .Where(e => e.SalesOrderHeader.OrderDate > startDate)
            .Where(e => e.SalesOrderHeader.OrderDate < endDate)
            .Join(db.Products, order => order.ProductID,
                product => product.ProductID,
                (order, product) => new OrderViewModel()
                {
                    Quantity = order.OrderQty,
                    UnitNet = order.UnitPrice,
                    DueDate = order.SalesOrderHeader.DueDate,
                    CustomerPO = order.SalesOrderHeader.PurchaseOrderNumber,
                    InvoiceNumber = order.SalesOrderHeader.SalesOrderNumber,
                    InvoiceTotal = order.SalesOrderHeader.TotalDue,
                    OrderDate = order.SalesOrderHeader.OrderDate,
                    AccountNumber = order.SalesOrderHeader.AccountNumber,
                    Store = order.SalesOrderHeader.Customer.Store.Name,
                    Customer = order.SalesOrderHeader.Customer.Person.FirstName + " " +
                               order.SalesOrderHeader.Customer.Person.LastName,
                    ProductNumber = product.ProductNumber
                }).Take(15);

        return View(model.ToList());
    }
```

Is there a way to "grab" this data and pass it into a second exportToExcel function? Or do I need to figure out how to parse it?

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the various methods
Make your `ActionMethod` return a `Json`
like:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetOrders(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
 //your code
 return Json(model.toList(),JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

.Make an Ajax call to `GetOrders` like:

```
   $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("GetOrders")',
            dataType: "json",
            data: { startDate: startDate, endDate: endDate, catid: catid, prdId: prdId, brandId: brandId },
            async: true,
            success: function (data) {
                   var htmlhead =    "<thead>       <tr><th style=\"width:6%; text-align:center;\"> Quantity</th> <th style=\"text-align:center;margin-left:4%;\">UnitNet</th><th style=\"text-align:center;margin-left:4%;\">DueDate</th></tr> </thead>";
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    htmlval = htmlval + ("<tr><td>" + data[i].Quantity + "</td><td style=\"text-align:center;\"> " + data[i].UnitNet + "</td><td style=\"text-align:center;\"> " + data[i].DueDate + "</td></tr>");
                }
                html = htmlhead + htmlval;
                $("#table").html(html);
                window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent($('div[id$=dvData]').html()));
            },

            error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
                console.log(jqXHR.responseText);

            }
        });
```

Do create a div with name "dvdata" and table like:

```
<div id="dvData" style="display:none;">

<table id="table"></table>
```

Or suppose you have Html Table in your view and you want to Download that table in Excel then see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/insin/cmewv/),[this](https://jsfiddle.net/lesson8/jWAJ7/) fiddle

Or You can use [this](http://w3lessons.info/2015/07/13/export-html-table-to-excel-csv-json-pdf-png-using-jquery/) plugin